# Как проверить повторяется ли символ в строке?

Tags: python

Как проверить повторяется ли символ в строке?

Comment: какой символ, сколько раз повторяется, что вообще значит "повторяется"?

Comment: встречается два раза, буква английского языка

Comment: метод count()  у строки?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

char = 'd'
string = 'abcdedf'
if Counter(string).get(char, 0) > 1:
    print('Символ ' + char + ' повторяется')
```

**UPD1:** Вариант без импортов

```
char = 'd'
string = 'abcdedf'

d = {}
for c in string:
    d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1

if d.get(char, 0) > 1:
    print('Символ ' + char + ' повторяется')
```

**UPD2:** Вариант для всех повторяющихся символов

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if v > 1:
        print('Символ ' + k + ' повторяется')
```

Comment: а как сделать без библиотек?

Comment: @АртемВитальев пакет `colletions` входит в стандартную библиотеку. Вам нужна реализация вообще без импортов?

Comment: да, желательно.

Comment: мне нужно не конкретный символ, а любой

Answer (score 1):

Вызовите метод `count` строк:

```
letter = 'A'
line = 'An apple'
line.count(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализация с помощью словаря. Без дополнительных библиотек. Для любого символа.

```
str = "строка с повтрными символами" 
dict_count = dict.fromkeys(str, 0) 
for c in str: 
    dict_count[c] += 1
```

Результат

> print (dict_count)
>
> {'с': 3, 'т': 2, 'р': 2, 'о': 3, 'к': 1, 'а': 2, ' ': 3, 'п': 1, 'в':
> 2, 'н': 1, 'ы': 1, 'м': 3, 'и': 3, 'л': 1}

Comment: Чем  не угодил вариант?

Comment: Что там, что у вас, мне кажется, очень сложно. Да, попробуйте `map()`.

Comment: а как по вашему через map?